# Picking the Right Reference Frame

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames

> A space vehicle travelling at $3860 \ \text {kmph}$ w.r.t Earth sends its exhausted rocket motor backward with a speed of $125 \ \text{kmph}$ w.r.t the command module. The mass of the rocket motor is $4$ times that of the command module. What is the speed of the command module after separation?

I've been practicing quite a few momentum related problems, but I've not quite got the hang of picking the right reference frame. In fact, the more problems (and their solutions) I encounter. The more confused I feel when picking the reference frame to solve the problem.

> Conservation of momentum. Let $m$ refer to motor and $c$ refer to command module:
>   $$p_{f,m} + p_{f,c} = p_{i,m} + p_{ic}$$
>   $$m_m(v_{f,c} - v_{\text{rel}}) + m_cv_{f,c} = (m_m + m_c)v_{i,c}$$
>   $$(m_m + m_c)v_{f,c} - m_mv_{\text{rel}} = (m_m + m_c)v_{i,c}$$
>   $$v_{f,c} = \frac {m_mv_{\text{rel}} + (m_m + m_c)v_{i,c}}{(m_m + m_c)}$$
>   $$ = \frac {4m_c(125 \ \text{km/h}) + (4mc + mc)(3860 \ \text{km/h})}{4m_c + m_c}$$
>   $$= \boxed {3960 \ \text{km/h}}.$$

For this problem, the author chose $v_{\text{rel}} = 125 \ \text{kmph}.$ Why did he do so? How does this help? And what reference frame did he choose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Let’s do this problem three ways

So there isn’t ever just one best choice; the mathematics works equally well in all reference frames and different people think in different ways.

To give you an idea of how the reference frame choice impacts our mathematics, let me work out the given example in three different reference frames.

### In the center-of-mass frame

For me and my way of thinking about things, usually my best overall choice is the **center of mass frame**. This is the frame in which there is **no momentum** before and after a collision. The fact that momentum has to sum to zero makes everything much easier to think about for me, kind of like how accountants like “balance sheets” where you have to get the same number on both sides, and how they invented double-entry bookkeeping to make the same check on an account-by-account basis.

On this account we would say that we were given the information that they both started off at velocity zero (since they were attached and the total momentum was zero) and then they flew off at velocities $v_{1,2}$ such that: $$m_1 v_1 + m_2 v_2 = 0,\\
v_1 - v_2 = 125\text{ km/hr},\\
m_2 = 4 m_1. $$
So for me this is a very easy set of equations to solve; if I define $q_i = v_i/(\text{1 km/hr})$ I have the two equations of dimensionless pure numbers, $$\begin{align}
q_1 + 4 q_2 &= 0\\
q_1 - q_2 &= 125\end{align}$$ and I can work out from subtracting such equations that $q_2 = (-125)/5=-25$ and then that $q_1 = 100$ and I can confirm afterwards that yes, $100 + 4\cdot(-25) = 0$ and that $100 - (-25) = 125.$ This is the “check” that I like to see.

And then for me it is no problem to then reason “okay, so the one part needs to be going $100 \text{ km/hr}$ faster than it was going, it was going at $\text{3860 km/hr}$ so now it must be going at $\text{3960 km/hr}.$”

## In Earth’s frame

But the point is that you might not find that latter reasoning about reference frames to be so automatic, or you might not find it so intuitive to deal with negatives (which you need, if things sum to zero!). And that is okay! If that’s true for you, you might prefer to instead set this up in Earth’s reference frame as, say, $$m_1 v_1 + m_2 v_2 = (m_1 + m_2) v_0,\\
v_0 = \text{3860 km/hr},\\
v_1 - v_2 = \text{125 km/hr},\\
m_2 = 4 m_1.$$ Then doing the same you will instead have $$\begin{align}
q_1 + 4 q_2 &= 5\cdot 3860 = 19300\\
q_1 - q_2 &= 125
\end{align}$$
and maybe you would like to add the second equation to the first four times instead, to get $5 q_1 = 19300 + 500$ or so, so that you again get $q_1 = 3960$, and this time we're in Earth's reference frame so we do not need to shift it at all.

In fact, your author chose *this* reference frame. You can see it by looking at what they substituted for this term $v_\text{i,c}$ above: they substituted $\text{3860 km/hr}$, exactly the measurement of the initial velocity if you keep Earth at a fixed place $v_\text{Earth} = 0.$

## In the command module's final frame

In both of the above, I had to do some linear algebra: I had to add and subtract equations and manipulate them to see what was going on. What if your brain does not like the above adding and subtracting of equations at all?

Then there is a clever way to look at the whole problem backwards. So, if you are *really* ambitious, you can choose the reference frame of the final command module, in other words choosing the reference frame where $v_1 = 0$. Lots of folks will not find this obvious, “you mean you want me to choose a *reference frame* where I don’t know *how fast it's going* relative to the Earth?!” Well, that is how this method works.

If I start by saying $v_1=0$ then I also know that $v_2 = -\text{125 km/hr}$ directly. What I don't know is the $v_0$, how fast these two were initially going. But that does not really need linear algebra to work out: I know that the total mass is 5 units and 4 of those units are flying away from the origin at $v_2,$ so I know that the center of mass is moving at speed $(4/5) v_2$, too, and just multiplying gives $v_0 = -\text{100 km/hr}$.

So then if Earth was moving $\text{3860 km/hr}$ relative to that, then it must be moving at $v_\text{Earth} = -\text{3960 km/hr}.$ No linear-algebra at all was needed, just one multiplication. In fact you did not even need negative numbers, if you change the direction that you think is “positive” so that $v_2-v_1 = \text{125 km/hr}$, but I didn’t want to make this too different from the previous two sections.

How did we do this? We tried explicitly to fix every single number that is available to us as soon as it was possible. We did not know what $m_1,m_2$ were so we just said “$m_1 = \text{1 unit},~~m_2=\text{4 units}.$” And we saw this equation $v_1 - v_2 = \text{125 km/hr}$ and we knew that we had a degree of freedom from reference frames, so we just decided, "OK, one assignment I can use would be $v_1 = 0, v_2 = -\text{125 km/hr}$," and we just ran with it. The idea is that you really try to make sure that at any given time you are dealing with very firm numbers in front of you. That is why we might choose this reference frame.

There is one more “natural” choice of reference frame, following the rocket motor's final velocity, but it basically has the same perspective with a slight bit of complication. There, one starts from the same equation but instead states that $v_1 = \text{125 km/hr}, v_2 = 0$ and the same argument suggests that $v_0 = (1/5)\text{ 125 km/hr} = \text{25 km/hr}$ from which you work out that $v_\text{Earth} = -\text{3835 km/hr}$ first, and then you get $3960 = 3835 + 125.$ So you still don't need to manipulate equations, it just takes you a little bit longer to get to that final result.

## Why I am showing you all three ways

Now part of why I am showing you both of these is that you **cannot** escape this equation that $v_1 - v_2 = \text{125 km/hr}$ in either situation. You can at most rotate the direction that it implicitly refers to, the $\pm$ alluded to before: you cannot change the magnitude.

Because: what is a different reference frame? It is some adding of some constant velocity $u$ to all of our $v_i$ to create some new $V_i = v_i + u$, and then *obviously* then we must have $$V_1 - V_2 = (v_1 + u) - (v_2 + u) = v_1 - v_2.$$ So velocity differences must be reference-frame-independent! Lots of other things are not reference-frame-independent, for example: energy is not (!), total momentum is also not. But relative velocities are. You were told that the relative velocity between the two things was a certain amount, then it will be that amount in all reference frames. So that answers your detailed question about $v_\text{rel}$: it was **given in the problem** and the author could not have chosen *any* reference frame to change that.

But what we can do is choose how these other equations look, either to do my preferred sort of center-of-mass “check that everything is zero” bookkeeping, or we can minimize the fuss we have about reference frames and transfer it all to our linear algebra of equations by choosing our answer’s preferred reference frame, or we can minimize the amount of fuss we have about those equations and move all of that to reasoning after-the-fact about reference frames. We have those freedoms.

It’s all mathematically equivalent, so it comes down to personal style and what comes natural to you. None of these ways is objectively better than any other way.

Comment: Wow! Long read, but worth it. It was really well explained. Thank you!